# How to select k distinct value by a field?

Tags: database, postgresql

How to select all infos from `k` distinct value of field `X`?

I have an idea to `group by` by some field `X` and then select like this

Table

```
id  name
1    x
2    y
3    x
4    y
5    z
6    w
```

Group by `name`:

```
id  name
1    x
3    x
2    y
4    y
5    z
6    w
```

Select `k=3` distinct value of `name`:

```
id  name
1    x
3    x
2    y
4    y
5    z
```

Any idea how to write this query?

Answer (score 0):

Try this -

```
WITH CTE AS (SELECT DISTINCT name
         FROM TAB
         LIMIT 3)
SELECT * FROM TAB
WHERE NAME IN (SELECT name FROM CTE)
ORDER BY name;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select id, name
from (
    select id, name, dense_rank() over (order by name) as ds
    from t
) s
where ds <= 3
```